# In a CSV file, subtotal 2 columns based on a third one, using AWK in KSH

Tags: awk, ksh

**Disclaimers:**

```
    1) English is my second language, so please forgive any grammatical horrors you may find. I am pretty confident you will be able to understand what I need despite these.
    2) I have found several examples in this site that address questions/problems similar to mine, though I was unfortunately not able to figure out the modifications that would need to be introduced to fit my needs.
```

**The "Problem":**

I have an CSV file that looks like this:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,134.6,,c8,c9,SERVER1,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,0,,c8,c9,SERVER1,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,0.18,,c8,c9,SERVER2,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,0,,c8,c9,SERVER2,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,416.09,,c8,c9,SERVER3,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,0,,c8,c9,SERVER3,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,12.1,,c8,c9,SERVER3,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,480.64,,c8,c9,SERVER4,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,83.65,c8,c9,SERVER5,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,253.15,c8,c9,SERVER6,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,18.84,c8,c9,SERVER7,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,8.12,c8,c9,SERVER7,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,22.45,c8,c9,SERVER7,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,117.81,c8,c9,SERVER8,c11
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,,96.34,c8,c9,SERVER9,c11
```

**Complementary facts:**

```
    1) File has 11 columns.
    2) The data in columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9 and 11 is irrelevant in this case. In other words, I will only work with columns 6, 7 and 10.
    3) Column 10 will be typically alphanumeric strings (server names), though it may contain also "-" and/or "_".
    4) Columns 6 and 7 will have exclusively numbers, with up to two decimal places (A possible value is 0). Only one of the two will have data per line, never both.
```

**What I need as an output:**

```
    - A single occurrence of every string in column 10 (as column 1), then the sum (subtotal) of it's values in column 6 (as column 2) and last, the sum (subtotal) of it's values in column 7 (as column 3).
    - If the total for a field is "0" the field must be left empty, but still must exist (it's respective comma has to be printed).
    - **Note** that the strings in column 10 will be already alphabetically sorted, so there is no need to do that part of the processing with AWK.
```

**Output sample, using the sample above as an input:**

```
SERVER1,134.6,,
SERVER2,0.18,,
SERVER3,428.19,,
SERVER4,480.64,,
SERVER5,,83.65
SERVER6,,253.15
SERVER7,,26.96
```

I've already found within these pages not one, but two AWK oneliners that PARTIALLY accomplish what it need:

```
awk -F "," 'NR==1{last=$10; sum=0;}{if (last != $10) {print last "," sum; last=$10; sum=0;} sum += $6;}END{print last "," sum;}' inputfile


awk -F, '{a[$10]+=$6;}END{for(i in a)print i","a[i];}' inputfile
```

**My "problems" in both cases are the same:**

```
    - Subtotals of 0 are printed.
    - I can only handle the sum of one column at a time. Whenever I try to add the second one, I get either a syntax error or it does simply not print the third column at all.
```

Thanks in advance for your support people!
Regards,
Martín

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
            {s6[$10]+=$6; s7[$10]+=$7} 
         END{for(k in s6) print k,(s6[k]?s6[k]:""),(s7[k]?s7[k]:"")}' file | sort

SERVER1,134.6,
SERVER2,0.18,
SERVER3,428.19,
SERVER4,480.64,
SERVER5,,83.65
SERVER6,,253.15
SERVER7,,49.41
SERVER8,,117.81
SERVER9,,96.34
```

note that your treatment of commas is not consistent, you're adding an extra one when the last field is zero (count the commas)

Comment: Karafka: You are right about the non consistent commas. Note that -as my code was not working- I had to put together that desired output manually, hence the error. By the way, you code worked like a cham!: cat input.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ; {s6[$10]+=$6; s7[$10]+=$7} ; END{for(k in s6) print k,(s6[k]?s6[k]:""),(s7[k]?s7[k]:"")}'
SERVER1,134.6,
SERVER2,0.18,
SERVER3,428.19,
SERVER4,480.64,
SERVER5,,83.65
SERVER6,,253.15
SERVER7,,49.41
SERVER8,,117.81
SERVER9,,96.34
Thank you very, very  much. I have already marked your answer as the correct one!

Comment: you're welcome.  Note that you don't need to use `cat` upfront.  `awk` can open files as well.  You don't need to pick the first answer but the one that you think is the best solution for your problem.  Over longer term that's a better approach.  The pros of this one is doesn't need sorted input.  Cons is it needs to be sorted afterwards.  If you don't have a sortable key and want to maintain the order in the input file perhaps other solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted expected output doesn't seem to match your posted sample input so we're guessing but this might be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$10 != prev {
    if (NR > 1) {
        print prev, sum6, sum7
    }
    sum6 = sum7 = ""
    prev = $10
}
$6  { sum6 += $6 }
$7  { sum7 += $7 }
END { print prev, sum6, sum7 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
SERVER1,134.6,
SERVER2,0.18,
SERVER3,428.19,
SERVER4,480.64,
SERVER5,,83.65
SERVER6,,253.15
SERVER7,,49.41
SERVER8,,117.81
SERVER9,,96.34
```

Comment: Ed: You are right about the output not matching the input. Note that -as my code was not working- I had to put together that desired output manually, hence the error. By the way, you code worked like a cham! too: cat input.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} ; $10 != prev {if (NR > 1) {print prev, sum6, sum7} ; sum6 = sum7 = "" ; prev = $10} ; $6  {sum6 += $6} ; $7  {sum7 += $7} ; END {print prev, sum6, sum7}'
SERVER1,134.6,
SERVER2,0.18,
SERVER3,428.19,
SERVER4,480.64,
SERVER5,,83.65
SERVER6,,253.15
SERVER7,,49.41
SERVER8,,117.81
SERVER9,,96.34  Thank you very, very much man!

Comment: I marked Karakfa's (also working) reply as the correct one because -since he replied earlier- it seemed the fairest thing to do. I wanted to mark your reply as well, but doing so seemed to un-mark my selection of karafka's reply. If there is a way I can mark both, please let me know and I will certainly do! Thanks again for taking the time to tackle on this ;)

Comment: No problem. The main difference between the 2 is that mine will always print your output in the order the servers appear in the input while karakfas will rearrange the lines based on alphabetic order of the server names. Add a SERVER10 line to the end of your input and then try both solutions to see what I mean (SERVER10 will appear after SERVER9 with mine but between SERVER1 and SERVER2 with karakfas). Also if your file gets really huge and then you'd want to use mine since mine just stores 2 sum integers in memory while karakfas keeps arrays indexed by all server names of both sums.